# Library for basic image manipulation in C++

Tags: c++, image-processing, grayscale

I am looking for a great C++ library for doing basic image manipulation. What I need done is to be able to convert an image to grayscale and have access to read the pixels of the image.

I have looked at OpenCV, GIL, CImg and Magick++, but either they were not too great, or I couldn't figure out how to convert an image to grayscale with the library.

Comment: If you're willing to try something other than C++, then there's Processing http://processing.org/ which is absolutely awesome for image manipulation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CImg is probably easiest to use, no install it's just a header file

Comment: Yeah, I kept with CImg as soon as i discovered that data-operator the CImg object has. It let's me easily create the image by values x, y, z, v: http://cimg.sourceforge.net/reference/structcimg__library_1_1CImg.html#a567d0f7b9c743a42958cfce84f8d432f

Comment: Also CImg stores images in planar color (a red image followed by a green, blue) which is a pain for display but makes it very easy to extra each of the color planes

Answer (score 6):

If you're going to convert color to greyscale on your own, you *don't* normally want to give equal weight to the three channels. The usual conversion is something like:

grey = 0.3 * R + 0.6 * G + 0.1 * B;

Obviously those factors aren't written in stone, but they should be reasonably close.

You can simulate different colors of filters by changing the factors -- by far the most common filter in B&W photography is red, which would mean increasing the red and decreasing the other two to maintain a total factor of 1.0 (but keep the G:B ratio around 6:1 or so).

Comment: I decided on these values for now:
0.3, 0.59, 0.11.

Answer (score 1):

You could also have a look at [CxImage](http://www.xdp.it/cximage.htm) (C++ image processing and conversion library) .

Answer (score 0):

To rough steps to do it using [Cimg](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/) would be something like:

```
#include "CImg.h"
using namespace cimg_library;
...
{
...
CImg<unsigned char> image("source.jpg") //[load jpg][2] needs ImageMagick
cimg_for(img,ptr,float) { *ptr=0; }      //[Loop][3] over every pixel, eg this method equivalent to 'img.fill(0);'
save_jpeg (const char *const filename, const unsigned int quality=100) //[save as a jpg][4] 
... 
}
```

- Cimg [stores its data](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/reference/group__cimg__storage.html) as a simple array.
- The [CImg varible](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/reference/group__cimg__faq.html#ssf23) is the object that represents the picture.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [Paintlib](http://www.paintlib.de/paintlib/)

Answer (score 0):

[ITK](http://www.itk.org/) is a great library for image processing. You can convert RGB to grayscale using `itk::RGBToLuminanceImageFilter`.